# Display the upcoming due dates based on the start date and end date determining from current date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Here is the spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I-7OYQx6eZ3a1AbxhBgOOpa632XNMh-gxKmGymnpxQ4/edit#gid=884845371)

I have the google spreadsheet where I need to display the date - if the current month is due for the payment

For example if  (today/current date) is Aug 1 and Due date for payment is Aug 28, then I must be seeing 28-Aug-2020 until the (today/current date) date is 28. When  (today/current date) date is Aug 29 it must disappear displaying

The "28" is considered as due date of the month and must be determined from Start date

**Start date** is where the installment begins and **end date** is where the installment ends

I have tried with `=DATE(YEAR(A3)+DATEDIF(A3,today(),"Y"),MONTH(A3)+D3*0, DAY(A3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following conventional formula:

```
=IF((MOD(MONTH(E3),D3)=MOD(MONTH(TODAY()),D3))*(DAY(E3)>=DAY(TODAY()))*(E3>=TODAY()),(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(E3))),"")
```

or array formula:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((MOD(MONTH(E3:E),D3:D)=MOD(MONTH(TODAY()),D3:D))*(DAY(E3:E)>=DAY(TODAY()))*(E3:E>=TODAY()),(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(E3:E))),"")),"")
```

[image]

Comment: The expected date is 28 aug, but here I see 28. Sep. Could you please let me know. For the third row. May 28 when added 3 months will get Aug 28.

Comment: @CodeGuy as you can see in screenshot, I changed ```End date``` to demonstrate the result because no date is currently displayed under your conditions.

Comment: Thanks so much really appreciated